# Vapor Crypto: expression type 'Data' is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift, cryptography, sha256, vapor

I am having a problem right now and don't know how to solve it.

I wrote a controller for managing my users. The following code is an excerpt from my registration function, where a key is generated for encrypting user data that is later stored in the database. The key (ekey) is stored in the database, too. So I need to encrypt the key and therefore I use a hash of the users password.

I'm getting this error on the last line:

```
Error: AES256GCM.encrypt: expression type 'Data' is ambiguous without more context
```

I don't know what is wrong with that.

```
// generate key for encrypting data
let ekey = try URandom().generateData(count: 32).base64EncodedString()

// generate digest for password and encrypt 'ekey'
let key: Data = try SHA256.hash(user.password)
let iv: Data = try URandom().generateData(count: 12)
let (encrKey, tag) = try AES256GCM.encrypt(ekey, key: key, iv: iv)
```

Comment: Is it possible that there are more that one class with name `Data`? In that case you have to use namespace to specify which one you want to use

Comment: I would try adding the expected type to that line and see if that fixes or gives you a different error:    `let (encrKey, tag): (Data, Data) = try AES256GCM.encrypt(ekey, key: key, iv: iv)`

Comment: I'm frequently getting this type of error if I forget to `import` the correct lib. The reason this doesn't cause an error is that other modules might implement related but not identical functionality, masking the lack of the correct signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, today I looked over the code again and changed the touple `(encrKey, tag)` to just `encrKey` and that worked for me.
I'm pretty shure, that it was in the doc's with a touple.

Anyways thanks for your replies!